# What is difference between for, name and id?

Tags: html, css

I wonder when I was using `<label>` tag. Where for attribute used for name. I can't understand. What is the exactly difference between for and name in html.

Comment: for more information : http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for=` attribute in the label is used to link the label to one specific input on the page.

Since `name=` is not unique for inputs (I can have multiple inputs with the same name), the `for=` element on the label links to an `id=` attribute on the input.

The `name` attribute is used to determine under what name to submit the input.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `for` attribute for label tag then it must be in form.
This will work with its associative `id` within the form.

Ex

```
<label for="name"> First Name </label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="firstname">
```

AND
`name` attribute can not be used in label. It can be used for those input for textarea or for those tag which are used to get or pass the value from the form.

Answer (score 3):

A label must be associated with a form control.

You can use a `for` attribute to create this association. If you do, then the value of the `for` attribute must be the same as the value of the `id` attribute of the form control.

There is no `name` attribute for label elements. The `name` attribute for form controls has nothing to do with labels (and is used as part of the algorithm used to construct the data to be sent to the server when the form is submitted).